# Spooler stops printing when more than one file is sent

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, printing, print-server

I have a problem that I am pulling my hair over!

On Windows Server 2012 R2 there are several shared, new, Canon printers.

Drivers are installer a new, and all is dandy. Or should be. However, when the users try to print more than one document, the documents are just kept in queue for some time before printing.

Often a half an hour is needed to print 5 1 page documents. However, when more documents are print at the same time, all prints OK.

Comment: How is the printer connected to the client? Over the network queue (print server) or directly (using LAN)? Could you please share the events from the client/server? Do you using any specific software (like SAP?). What kind of driver is in use? PCL or PS3

Comment: Tried both PCL6, PS and UFR2. No other specific apps. Tested AV turned off both on clients and on server. They all print to server, which is a print server for the printers, over network. (Printers are LAN printers.)

Comment: Have you checked print queue on the server? Try to change Spool print policy (Advanced tab in printer properties) to "Start printing after last page is spooled". Also, I would recommend checking "Print spooled documents first" and uncheck "Enable advanced printing features". Additionally, you can enable "Render print job on client devices" or disable in "Sharing" tab

Comment: I did all of listed stuff before I posted here. No change happened. I am certain that the printer works fine, because all jobs that get to it print immediately (took a look in the printer logs).